# Actions not firing on elements contained in a Foundation modal

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

I have a component template set up as such:

```
<div id="clipModal" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h3>New Clip</h3>

  <p class="margin-top-10">
    <label>Title:</label>
    {{input value=title }}
  </p>

  {{widgets/video-player/project-selector projects=projects action='selectedProjectChanged'}}

  <p>
    <label>Duration</label>
      {{formattedSelectionStart}} - {{formattedSelectionEnd}}
  </p>

  <p>
    <button {{action "clip"}}>Create Clip</button>
  </p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>  
</div>
```

And this has the associated action defined within the component itself. I won't paste that code, for brevity.

The 'clip' action is never handled, despite showing `data-ember-action="1024"` in the output HTML in the DOM.

Now, what's tripping me up. If I stop that template being a Foundation modal by removing the necessary classes and properties, the event fires properly when I click the 'Create clip' button. Ditto if I simply move that button outside of the modal.

Any idea what could possibly be causing this? Elements with inline vanilla JS events within that modal work correctly, as do all the Foundation events themselves. It's just Ember refusing to play ball for whatever reason.

I get absolutely no feedback in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after much poking around, it turns out the root of the problem was my defining a custom `rootElement` in my application instantiation. So when Foundation was inserting its modal gubbins, it shoved them *outside* the Ember application into the `body`, which then obviously meant the events weren't being observed by Ember.

edit: The solution, which allows you to still have Ember in its own custom container, is to set the `root_element` when instantiating any Foundation modules.

```
Ember.$(document).foundation('reveal', { root_element: $("#someFragment") });
```